# Two dimensional convolution in matlab . Result differs from conv2 of matlab toolbox.Any tip?

Tags: arrays, matlab, signals, convolution

```
[r,c] = size(x);
[m,n] = size(y);
h = rot90(y, 2);
center = floor((size(h)+1)/2);
Rep = zeros(r + m*2-2, c + n*2-2);
return

for x1 = m : m+r-1
for y1 = n : n+r-1
    Rep(x1,y1) = x(x1-m+1, y1-n+1);
end
end

B = zeros(r+m-1,n+c-1);
for x1 = 1 : r+m-1
for y1 = 1 : n+c-1
    for i = 1 : m
        for j = 1 : n
            B(x1, y1) = B(x1, y1) + (Rep(x1+i-1, y1+j-1) * h(i, j));
        end
    end
end
end
Con=conv2(Rep,h);
```

I have this code for 2d convolution.But Con and B are different(last column of correct convolution(=Con) does not exist in B,and other elements also differ.I cant understand what i do wrong.

Comment: you have to specify the shape in conv2, see the [documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) for more information.

Comment: As i see conv2 result is right.The problem is with the algorithm above.